# Writing a python wrapper for c++ code

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython

I modified a  C++ code (Kraskov_v1.C) and I now wish to call it from Python.

I am able to convert the C++ code (Kraskov_v1.C) into a .so file and integrate it into my python library. However when I try and import the library, it throws up an error. The error says "undefined symbol: _Z8mir_xnynPPdiiiiS_S_S_"

mir_xn_yn is a function (written in another c++ file namely miutils) that my Kraskov_v1 code calls. I included the header file

## include "miutils.h"

in my file containing Kraskov_v1.

Here is the setup.py file I wrote to build and install this package.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy.distutils.misc_util

setup(name='Kraskov_v1',
      version='0.1.0',
      ext_modules=[Extension('_Kraskov_v1',sources =        
      ["Kraskov_v1.i","Kraskov_v1.C"],
      include_dirs = ['src'])
      ])
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Can someone tell me whats wrong? I am new to python and c++ and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do I need to link the miutils.h library in the setup file?

Answer (score 0):

The `Extension` needs a list of libraries to link with after compiling.

Missing symbols means a required library is not linked to the shared object (`.so`) and definitions from that library are not available.

```
setup(name='Kraskov_v1',
      version='0.1.0',
      ext_modules=[Extension('_Kraskov_v1',sources =        
          ["Kraskov_v1.i","Kraskov_v1.C"],
          include_dirs = ['src']),
          libraries=['kraskov', <..>],
      ])
```

Comment: Hi danny thanks a lot for your response! It was very useful. Unfortunately I am still having a problem. So firstly the libraries I need to add is "miutils" not "kraskov". I added this as you can see above. I also added the path to the field library_dirs as this is a non-standard path. However when I try and run the setup.py file it throws up an error namely "cannot find -lmiutils".  Since I added the non-standard path why is not able to find it? I should also mention that the miutils is just a .c and .h file. Do I need to first convert this to another format? Please let me know. Best

Comment: Here are the 3 commands I call from the terminal:  swig -python -module Kraskov_v1 Kraskov_v1.h
gcc -c -fPIC Kraskov_v1_wrap.c -o _Kraskov_v1.so
python setup_v1.py build install

Comment: I wrote the setup file according to the documentation here https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html

Comment: Which details [how to link libraries](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#library-options).